# Uncaught Typerror: object is not a function - Conditionizr

Tags: javascript

For the life of me I cannot see where I am going wrong with this. link: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/landstar/

I am trying to setup Conditionizr but am getting the above issue, and the class of 'chrome' is not being added to the html tag.

My header.php looks like this:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?> 
 <script>                       

 conditionizr.add('chrome', ['class'], function () {
  return !!window.chrome && /google/i.test(navigator.vendor);
 });

 </script>
</head>
```

I am calling conditionizr via functions.php and it's added to the header before the above calls. I deleted all of the other JS on the site, but that didnt help. I got the same result.

I'm not sure where else I am going wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always read [the documentation](https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/blob/master/docs/DOCS.md#conditionizradd). `.add()` has **two arguments**. Your configuration belongs in `.config`:

```
conditionizr.config({
    assets: '/path/to/my/assets/',
    tests: {    
        'chrome': ['class']
    }
});

conditionizr.add('chrome', function () {
    return !!window.chrome && /google/i.test(navigator.vendor);
});
```

Comment: You don't have to use the config call for the tests. In this instance I added the config call underneath the test and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @HuwRowlands: You're welcome. I just used the information from the documentation for my answer, since I haven't used conditionizr myself yet.